# Why doesn't my grid grow when I enlarge the program?

Tags: wpf, xaml

So my code looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border Background="#FFFFFF" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="1009" Height="30">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnToolbarMin" Content="─" Height="30" Width="44"  Style="{StaticResource ButtonTempplate}" Click="btnToolbarMin_Click"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnToolbarMax" Content="£" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" Height="30" Width="44" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTempplate}" Click="btnToolbarMax_Click" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnToolbarClose" Content="Ñ" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" Height="30" Width="44" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTempplate}" Click="btnToolbarClose_Click" />
                </Grid>
        </Border>
            <StackPanel Background="#F5F5F5" Height="70" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="336*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="627*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="46*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Margin="13 10 0 0" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Artikel" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="15" Foreground="#38C72E" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="58"/>
                <Menu Grid.Row="1" Background="#F5F5F5" Margin="13,0,282,11" >
                    <MenuItem  Header="≡"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15">
                        <MenuItem Header="WW" FontSize="10"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
                <Button Content="↻" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="42"/>
                <Button Content="­☼" FontSize="15" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="43"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Background="#F5F5F5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="40">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Content="Dummy1" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" Width="115" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5 10 13 0"/>
                <Button Content="Dummy2" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="115" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

And when I press the max button (i.e. the one next to the close button) with this code:

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Then he lets several things grow with it, but some things like the top bar, for example, where the 3 buttons are to close, minimize and not grow with them, why is that? I also worked with dock panel and horizontal and vertical alignment, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you set the `Width` of the top bar explicitly, which leads to the bar not being shown when the window is small and being centered when the window is larger that size.

```
<Border ... Width="1009" ...>
```

The same applies to the explicit `Height="30"` in the `Border`. The height is fixed, so of course it does not scale with the window.